# Crashes when converting from RGB to HSV and CMYK

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and I am trying to convert from RGB to both HSV and CMYK.  I have the following two methods which convert the values:

```
public void convertHSV() {
    android.graphics.Color.RGBToHSV(Color.red(bgColor), Color.green(bgColor), Color.blue(bgColor), hsvColor);
    TextView hValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hValue);
    TextView sValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sValue);
    TextView vValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vValue);

    hValue.setText(String.valueOf(hsvColor[1]));
    sValue.setText(String.valueOf(hsvColor[2]));
    vValue.setText(String.valueOf(hsvColor[3]));
}

public void convertCMYK() {
    String CValue;
    String MValue;
    String YValue;
    String KValue;

    int computedC;
    int computedM;
    int computedY;
    int computedK;
    int minCMY;

    TextView cyanValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cyanValue);
    TextView magentaValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.magentaValue);
    TextView yellowValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yellowValue);
    TextView blackValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blackValue);


    if (hexRed == "00" && hexGreen == "00" && hexBlue == "00") {

        CValue = "0";
        MValue = "0";
        YValue = "0";
        KValue = "1";

    } else {
        computedC = 1 - (Integer.parseInt(hexRed) / 255);
        computedM = 1 - (Integer.parseInt(hexGreen) / 255);
        computedY = 1 - (Integer.parseInt(hexBlue) / 255);

        minCMY = Math.min(computedC, Math.min(computedM, computedY));

        computedC = (computedC - minCMY) / (1 - minCMY);
        computedM = (computedM - minCMY) / (1 - minCMY);
        computedY = (computedY - minCMY) / (1 - minCMY);
        computedK = minCMY;

        CValue = Integer.toString(computedC);
        MValue = Integer.toString(computedM);
        YValue = Integer.toString(computedY);
        KValue = Integer.toString(computedK);
    }

    cyanValue.setText(CValue);
    magentaValue.setText(MValue);
    yellowValue.setText(YValue);
    blackValue.setText(KValue);
}
```

I call these methods when each slider is changed:

```
 SeekBar blueBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.blueBar);

    final TextView blueBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blueValue);

    blueBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar blueBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            blueBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            bgColor = Color.rgb(Color.red(bgColor), Color.green(bgColor), progress);
            hexBlue = Integer.toHexString(progress);
            if (hexBlue.length() == 1) {
                hexBlue = "0" + hexBlue;
            }
            updateBackgroundColor();
            updateHexValue();
            convertHSV();
            //convertCMYK();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar blueBarValue) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar blueBarValue) {

        }
    });
```

When I use the sliders the app just crashes in the emulator.  I tried only calling them when the user lets go of the sliders but it still caused it to crash.  Why is this happening?

Comment: What are the types of `hexRed`, `hexGreen` and `hexBlue`?  I can't see their declarations.

Comment: Please include the exception stack trace from Logcat. http://imgur.com/jacoj

Comment: After a huge amount of fiddling around and harassing a software engineer i know i worked out it was to do with parsing the hexadecimal incorrectly. Had to make it:
'computedC = 1 - (Integer.parseInt(hexRed, 16) / 255);'